# Twilio sip call is not working from tryit.jssip.net

Tags: twilio, webrtc, sip

I am using Twilio to make sip outgoing calls. I have created a sip domain, registered credential lists. Then i registered in `Zoiper` using the sip credentials and made an outbound call. It was working successfully.
Similarly i tried using `tryit.jssip.net`. But there it was asking for a WebSocket uri. What is that `WebSocket uri` for twilio ?
Is there something to do more in twilio to register sip endpoint in tryit.jssip.net

Sharing the screenshots here.

1. This is the jssip configuration. I entered sip uri and password. Websocket url is by default `wss://tryit.jssip.net:10443`. I didn't change it.
   [image: Jssip configuration]
2. Then it got registered and i tried calling from that number. At that time the call got failed with a message `Incompatible UDP`
   [image: Incompatible UDP when tried calling]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking for there. I just tried to use `tryit.jssip.net` and it was asking me for a username or SIP address. Where are you seeing that option? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: @philnash I have added the screenshots. I have tried the same with "bandwidth" sip uri and password. At that time i gave WebSocket Uri as `wss://webrtc.registration.bandwidth.com:10443`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Twilio doesn't publicly support SIP over websockets which JSSIP is asking for here. That is why you can't find the websocket URL to use.

If you are looking to use Twilio from a web browser, I suggest you take a look at [Twilio Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript).

Comment: I had created a Twilio client by using an access token. When i tried calling from that client, the Twiml Application callback url was invoked instead of SIP domain callback url. When i called from Zoiper, domain callback url was invoked. How can i invoke domain callback url when i call using Twilio client ?

Comment: Twilio Client doesn’t use the SIP domain, so you can’t invoke the domain callback with it. If you want to use SIP, you’ll need a SIP client that doesn’t work over websockets. If you want to use Twilio in the browser, Twilio Client is your way forward.

Comment: Not that I know of, I'm afraid.

Comment: Is it possible to use such SIP clients to work with Twilio in browser ?

Comment: No. As I've said, if you want to work with Twilio in the browser you will want to use Twilio Client.

Comment: Okay thanks, then what about a mobile application ? Can i use sip clients to call from mobile app ?

Comment: I have configured Linphone on iOS using Twilio SIP successfully, so I would assume that you can use a SIP client to call from a mobile app. (There is also the [Programmable Voice SDK](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/voip-sdk) for building Twilio into a mobile app too.)

Comment: I notice that you can call with JsSip to twilio by creating proxy server (overSip) for example